# Angular - How to use Conditional NgClasses?

Tags: angular, ng-class

Good morning

I've been adding conditional CSS classes or as angular calls it NgClasses to my component, but I'm only facing more and more errors!

What am I doing wrong?

The error messages I'm receiving:

```
    compiler.es5.js:1689 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Missing expected : at column 5 in [{key.class: true, 'active': key.enabled}] in ng:///AppModuleShared/KeyboardComponent.html@3:45 ("s]="{'signup-button': key.class == 'signup-button'}">
            <button [disabled]="key.enabled" [ERROR ->][ngClass]="{key.class: true, 'active': key.enabled}" (click)="keyboardservice.selectKey(key.key)" *ng"): ng:///AppModuleShared/KeyboardComponent.html@3:45
Parser Error: Unexpected token } at column 40 in [{key.class: true, 'active': key.enabled}] in ng:///AppModuleShared/KeyboardComponent.html@3:45 ("s]="{'signup-button': key.class == 'signup-button'}">
            <button [disabled]="key.enabled" [ERROR ->][ngClass]="{key.class: true, 'active': key.enabled}" (click)="keyboardservice.selectKey(key.key)" *ng"): ng:///AppModuleShared/KeyboardComponent.html@3:45
Parser Error: Missing expected : at column 5 in [{key.class: true, 'active': key.enabled}] in ng:///AppModuleShared/KeyboardComponent.html@3:45 ("
            <button [disabled]="key.enabled" [ngClass]="{key.class: true, 'active': key.enabled}" [ERROR ->](click)="keyboardservice.selectKey(key.key)" *ngIf="!key.actionButton" class="keyboard-button">{{key."): ng:///AppModuleShared/KeyboardComponent.html@3:98
Parser Error: Unexpected token } at column 40 in [{key.class: true, 'active': key.enabled}] in ng:///AppModuleShared/KeyboardComponent.html@3:45 ("
            <button [disabled]="key.enabled" [ngClass]="{key.class: true, 'active': key.enabled}" [ERROR ->](click)="keyboardservice.selectKey(key.key)" *ngIf="!key.actionButton" class="keyboard-button">{{key."): ng:///AppModuleShared/KeyboardComponent.html@3:98
Parser Error: Missing expected : at column 5 in [{key.class: true, 'active': key.enabled}] in ng:///AppModuleShared/KeyboardComponent.html@3:45 ("" [ngClass]="{key.class: true, 'active': key.enabled}" (click)="keyboardservice.selectKey(key.key)" [ERROR ->]*ngIf="!key.actionButton" class="keyboard-button">{{key.key}}</button>
            <button [disabled"): ng:///AppModuleShared/KeyboardComponent.html@3:143
Parser Error: Unexpected token } at column 40 in [{key.class: true, 'active': key.enabled}] in ng:///AppModuleShared/KeyboardComponent.html@3:45 ("" [ngClass]="{key.class: true, 'active': key.enabled}" (click)="keyboardservice.selectKey(key.key)" [ERROR ->]*ngIf="!key.actionButton" class="keyboard-button">{{key.key}}</button>
            <button [disabled"): ng:///AppModuleShared/KeyboardComponent.html@3:143
Parser Error: Missing expected : at column 5 in [{key.class: true, 'active': key.enabled}] in ng:///AppModuleShared/KeyboardComponent.html@3:45 ("ed}" (click)="keyboardservice.selectKey(key.key)" *ngIf="!key.actionButton" class="keyboard-button">[ERROR ->]{{key.key}}</button>
            <button [disabled]="key.enabled" [ngClass]="key.class" [routerLink]"): ng:///AppModuleShared/KeyboardComponent.html@3:193
Parser Error: Unexpected token } at column 40 in [{key.class: true, 'active': key.enabled}] in ng:///AppModuleShared/KeyboardComponent.html@3:45 ("ed}" (click)="keyboardservice.selectKey(key.key)" *ngIf="!key.actionButton" class="keyboard-button">[ERROR ->]{{key.key}}</button>
            <button [disabled]="key.enabled" [ngClass]="key.class" [routerLink]"): ng:///AppModuleShared/KeyboardComponent.html@3:193
Parser Error: Missing expected : at column 5 in [{key.class: true, 'active': key.enabled}] in ng:///AppModuleShared/KeyboardComponent.html@3:45 ("y.key)" *ngIf="!key.actionButton" class="keyboard-button">{{key.key}}</button>
            <button [ERROR ->][disabled]="key.enabled" [ngClass]="key.class" [routerLink]="['/Change-Language']" *ngIf="key.actionB"): ng:///AppModuleShared/KeyboardComponent.html@4:20
Parser Error: Unexpected token } at column 40 in [{key.class: true, 'active': key.enabled}] in ng:///AppModuleShared/KeyboardComponent.html@3:45 ("y.key)" *ngIf="!key.actionButton" class="keyboard-button">{{key.key}}</button>
            <button [ERROR ->][disabled]="key.enabled" [ngClass]="key.class" [routerLink]="['/Change-Language']" *ngIf="key.actionB"): ng:///AppModuleShared/KeyboardComponent.html@4:20
Parser Error: Missing expected : at column 5 in [{key.class: true, 'active': key.enabled}] in ng:///AppModuleShared/KeyboardComponent.html@3:45 ("nButton" class="keyboard-button">{{key.key}}</button>
            <button [disabled]="key.enabled" [ERROR ->][ngClass]="key.class" [routerLink]="['/Change-Language']" *ngIf="key.actionButton && key.class == 'la"): ng:///AppModuleShared/KeyboardComponent.html@4:45
Parser Error: Unexpected token } at column 40 in [{key.class: true, 'active': key.enabled}] in ng:///AppModuleShared/KeyboardComponent.html@3:45 ("nButton" class="keyboard-button">{{key.key}}</button>
            <button [disabled]="key.enabled" [ERROR ->][ngClass]="key.class" [routerLink]="['/Change-Language']" *ngIf="key.actionButton && key.class == 'la"): ng:///AppModuleShared/KeyboardComponent.html@4:45
```

My code:

```
<div class="keyboard-wrapper" [ngClass]="keyboardservice.ticketNumberInfo['TicketNumberType']" >
    <div class="keyboard-holder">
        <div class="key-holder" *ngFor="let key of keyboardservice.createKeyboard(keyboardservice.keyboardKeys)" [ngClass]="{'signup-button': key.class == 'signup-button'}">
            <button [disabled]="key.enabled" [ngClass]="{key.class: true, 'active': key.enabled}" (click)="keyboardservice.selectKey(key.key)" *ngIf="!key.actionButton" class="keyboard-button">{{key.key}}</button>
            <button [disabled]="key.enabled" [ngClass]="key.class" [routerLink]="['/Change-Language']" *ngIf="key.actionButton && key.class == 'language-button'" class="keyboard-button"><i class="fas fa-globe"></i></button>
            <button [disabled]="key.enabled" [ngClass]="key.class" (click)="keyboardservice.deselectKey()" *ngIf="key.actionButton && key.class == 'back-button'" class="keyboard-button"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></button>
            <button [disabled]="key.enabled" [ngClass]="key.class" (click)="alert('word gebouwd')" *ngIf="key.actionButton && key.class == 'signup-button'" class="keyboard-button">Aanmelden</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***Weirdest thing is that the first button doesn't work.
But the bottom 3 do.
The problem seems to be that angular doesn't want to use dynamic variables when evaluating multiple classes.***

Comment: key.class should be string not object value

Comment: Definitely not. When making it a string it puts the string "key.class" but key.class is an actual object with the key class. which contains a class.

Comment: yeah i know, i mean to say that don't use key.class dynamically, use only string instead of key.class
example:- [ngClass] ="{'col-md-6', key.enabled}"

Comment: Yea but that's the whole point. I'm creating a dynamic keyboard which has dynamic classes based on some data.

Comment: Also @SharmaVikram it works with the bottom 3 buttons.
Only the top button can't paste it's class.

Comment: you should try this
<button [ngClass]="key.class === 'newclass' ?key.class : ''"></button>

Comment: @Rick-HashtagNetwork Could you maybe create a stackblitz with mock data?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so understandable in the end.
It turned out that I shouldn't use any variables which don't need any evaluation within NgClass.

Instead, any fixed value should be added to the regular class definition within your HTML with some interpolation.

Also directly checking if something is exactly the same as a string, is dirty and should use .contains instead
(Did this in my NgIf's)

The final code should be.

```
<div class="keyboard-wrapper" [ngClass]="keyboardservice.ticketNumberInfo['TicketNumberType']" >
    <div class="keyboard-holder">
        <div class="key-holder" *ngFor="let key of keyboardservice.createKeyboard(keyboardservice.keyboardKeys)" [ngClass]="{'signup-button': key.class.includes('signup-button')}">
            <button [disabled]="key.enabled" class="{{key.class}} keyboard-button" [ngClass]="{'active' : key.enabled}" (click)="keyboardservice.selectKey(key.key)" *ngIf="!key.actionButton">{{key.key}}</button>
            <button [disabled]="key.enabled" class="{{key.class}} keyboard-button" [ngClass]="{'active' : key.enabled}" [routerLink]="['/Change-Language']" *ngIf="key.class.includes('language-button')" ><i class="fas fa-globe"></i></button>
            <button [disabled]="key.enabled" class="{{key.class}} keyboard-button" [ngClass]="{'active' : key.enabled}" (click)="keyboardservice.deselectKey()" *ngIf="key.class.includes('back-button')" ><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></button>
            <button [disabled]="key.enabled" class="{{key.class}} keyboard-button" [ngClass]="{'active' : key.enabled}" (click)="alert('word gebouwd')" *ngIf="key.class.includes('signup-button')">Aanmelden</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```